# auto-loader in Zend Framework 3.0.3-dev

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-autoloader, zend-http-client

Being novice to Zend framework and after reading almost all the possible answers already posted, It did not work. I want to set up an instance of Zend Framework auto-loader and Zend_Http_Client class.
code is as:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
zend_autoload::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
```

I see also that 'Zend/Loader.php' is deprecated in the previous versions and is as now: 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'; Then I can not locate the class 'zend_autoload'. Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? Any errors? Did you read the docs as they are since ZF3 on [zendframework.github.io](http://zendframework.github.io/) ? Have you had a look at the [Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication)? If you grab the docs and work along in the Skeleton Application throughout the [Tutorials](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/), you should understand the basics :)

Comment: @rkeet Yes, I did read the documentation. Wrote here only when it did not make sense. This is the error I am coming across: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'zend_autoload' not found in`  I hope your little explanation can help me get to track.

Comment: Can I ask which editor you're using? Your IDE should've given you a notice that a class in ZF does not exist by that name. I think the class you're looking for is `\Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader`.

Comment: @ I am using Notepad ++

Comment: I highly recommend you give [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) a try. ^^ Highly! ^^